# How to select a network of linked records?

Tags: mysql

So, I'm thinking about building a database for family trees. There's a table for people, and there's a table linking people to other people, by spouse or parent relationships.

Later, if I want to pull all the people related to a specific individual, how would I do that efficiently with mysql?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)